# How can I validate white space?

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have to validate a `String` with only white spaces. In my `String` white spaces between a `String` is allowed but only white spaces not allowed. For example `"conditions apply"`,`"conditions"` etc is allowed but not `"  "`. ie, only white space not allowed

I want a regular expression in JavaScript for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this regular expression

```
".*\\S+.*"
```

Comment: I think it can be achieved using the same regex by delimiting using /'s. i.e. `/.*\\S+.*/` works. I'm not sure as I am not thorough with regex in javascript.

Answer (score 7):

Do you really need to use a regex?

```
if (str.trim().length() == 0)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

As mentionned in the comments, this could be simplified to a one-liner

```
return str.trim().length() > 0;
```

or, since Java 6

```
return !str.trim().isEmpty();
```

Comment: `return str.trim().length() != 0;`

Comment: @gefei: `return str.trim().length() > 0;`

Comment: @Cerbrus `return !str.trim().isEmpty();`

Comment: Well played, @assylias. You win this round.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
// This does replace all whitespaces at the end of the string
String s = "      ".trim();
if(s.equals(""))
    System.out.println(true);
else 
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

what about checking if the string does not match `"\\s+"`?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is `^\\s*$` is used to match a whitespace only string, you can validate against this.

```
^     # Match the start of the string 
\\s*  # Match zero of more whitespace characters
$     # Match the end of the string
```

Anchoring to the start and the end of the string is important here.

Comment: Guys, this is a valid answer.
This Regex can be used to check is a string _only_ contains whitespaces. If this regex validates, the string isn't allowed.
@NaveedS: Your regex doesn't validate for strings containing no spaces.

Comment: @NaveedS: That is **exactly** why this regex works. If this regex validates, that means the string is "bad". If the regex doesn't validate, the string is "legit".